# AAR not including module's resources

Tags: java, android, gradle, resources, aar

I have an Android library that is composed of 2 modules :

```
Project Root
+-- moduleA
|   +-- src
|   \-- build.gradle
|
+-- moduleB
|   +-- src
|   \-- build.gradle
|
+-- build.gradle
+-- settings.gradle
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':moduleB', 'moduleA'
```

**moduleA/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...
dependencies {
    compile project(':moduleB')
}
```

**moduleB/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...
```

When I try to use the AAR generated by gradle, the moduleB's resources are not included.
I tried to push both AARs to maven local but same result.

If I change moduleA's type to `application` instead of `library`, the generated APK includes the correct resources.

What should I do so I can get an AAR that contains both modules resources?

Answer (score 3):

That is by design.

You have 2 options:

1. publish both modules as AAR libraries (using something like this: https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin). This way, `LibraryA` will mark a dependency on `LibraryB` and import it, including resources using classical methods.
2. build a fat AAR (using something like this: https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar). This is basically what you were expecting to happen.